# How to use following equation by using Green's function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Let's have the following equation:
$$
u''(r) + \frac{1}{r}u'(r) - \alpha^{2}u(r) = f(r),
$$
where $r$ is polar radius.

Method of Green's function leads to
$$
u''(r) + \frac{1}{r}u'(r) - \alpha^{2}u(r) = \delta(r). \qquad (1)
$$
Here I have little trouble.

It seems that the solution is $C_{1}I_{0}(\alpha r) + C_{2}K_{0}(\alpha r)$, where $I_{0}, K_{0}$ are Infeld and Macdonald functions respectively. But I don't know how to choose constants. It's obvious that Macdonald functions is correct solution of $(1)$, but I don't sure that I can set $C_{2},C_{1}$ to $1, 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{u''(r) + \frac{1}{r}u'(r) - \alpha^{2}u(r) = f}$
$$
u\pars{r}
=
{\rm u_{p}}\pars{r} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm G}\pars{r,r'}f\pars{r'}\,\dd r'
$$
where ${\rm u}_{p}\pars{r}$ is a solution of
$\ds{u''(r) + \frac{1}{r}u'(r) - \alpha^{2}u = 0}$ which satisfies the given boundary conditions. ${\rm G}\pars{r,r'}$ is the Green function which satisfies
$$
\pars{\partiald[2]{}{r} + {1 \over r}\partiald{}{r} - \alpha^{2}}G\pars{r,r'}
=
\delta\pars{r - r'}
$$
${\rm G}\pars{r,r'}$, as a function of $r$, satisfies homogeneous boundary conditions.

Comment: But can you comment my solution?